# Puzzling "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch" only during loop using portopt & ewstats

Tags: matlab

I am tearing my hair out over this one.

I have a set of daily returns of 4 assets, using a 10 day window I loop over the whole dataset (from `i` = 1 to 50) performing a number of calculations and building optimal portfolios. This involves using `portopt`.

```
[PortRisk(:,i), PortReturn(:,i), PortWts(:,:,i)] = portopt(ExpReturn(i,:), ExpCovariance(:,:,i), [], [], ConSet);
```

The inputs, `ExpReturn` and `ExpCovariance` are generated using `ewstats`

```
[ExpReturn(i,:), ExpCovariance(:,:,i)] = ewstats(RetSeries, 0.94)
```

Now, on the final 50th iteration (and only the 50th - all previous work fine), I get the following error:

```
??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch. Error in ==> Script at 10
[PortRisk(:,i), PortReturn(:,i), PortWts(:,:,i)] = portopt(ExpReturn(i,:), ExpCovariance(:,:,i), [], [], ConSet);
```

Note, I see no issue with `RetSeries` as `ExpReturn` and `ExpCovariance` generated by `ewstats` are size `<50x4>` and `<4x4x50>` respectively.

I have tried everything i can think of to hunt down the error, including checking `size()`, using breakpoints, preallocating the matrices etc etc. Oddly, if i remove the loop, set `i = 50`, it works. Furthermore, if instead of `ewstats` I simply use `mean()` and `cov()` - they work on the 50th iteration. If i replace one, `ExpReturn` for example, with a `mean(RetSeries)`, it works. Similarly, replacing `ExpCovariance` with `cov(RetSeries)` - works. But both `ExpReturn` and `ExpCovariance` together always fail.

What is causing the error?

EDIT:

Using `dbstop if error`, I can see:

```
PortRisk <10x50>
PortReturn <10x50>
PortWts<10x4x49>
ExpReturn <50x4>
ExpCovariance<4x4x50>
```

so the problem is `PortWts` but I do not understand why now it is not the right dimensions when it was for 49 other iterations. Also, the offending error line is the first point in the loop `PortWts` is mentioned, so nothing is messing with it beforehand

Comment: You are sure that for every i, those outputs have the same number of rows (and columns in the case of PortWts)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `dbstop if error`, and run your code again. MATLAB will enter debug mode at the exact point where the error occurs.

Here is a [screencast](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2008/04/28/matlab-basics-using-dbstop-if-error/) by Doug Hull showing how

---

#### EDIT

Change the offending line to:

```
[a,b,c] = portopt(ExpReturn(i,:), ExpCovariance(:,:,i), [], [], ConSet);
```

then assign each individually:

```
PortRisk(:,i)  a;
PortReturn(:,i) = b;
PortWts(:,:,i) = c;
```

Now when it fails, it will show you exactly which output did not have the expected size. Combined with the above trick, you can now inspect the variables in your workspace at the time of the error, and figure out what is wrong..

---

#### EDIT2

In addition, add the following test in between the two (before assigning):

```
if isempty(a) || isempty(b) || isempty(c)
    keyboard          %# enter debug mode. Or issue an error
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I noted above the the issue appears to be the size of PortWts<10x4x49> ie not <10x4x50> but I am utterly puzzled as to why this is (this is the first point in the loop that PortWts is mentioned so nothing else is messing with it before that). Ill update my question

Comment: @Ryan: did you preallocate the matrices before the loop (as in `PortWts = zeros(10,4,50);`? Also I would be interested in the size of `a`, `b`, and `c` in the above code at the time of the error...

Comment: Yes, I preallocated all the matrices outside the loop. After I get the error, the `size()` of `a`, `b` and `c` are:  `10    50`,  `10    50`,  `10     4    50` (ie what i would want), but in my workspace i can see `<10x50>`, `<10x50>`, `<10x4x49>` (ie `PortWts` is the issue). Also note, `PortWts(:,:,50)` gives a zeros matrix (from preallocation - but not an index out of bounds, so where is the dimension mismatch?!)

Comment: I suspect that at one point in the iterations, `c` was an empty matrix. Thus when you assign  `PortWts(:,:,i) = c` you are effectively removing a "slice" from the 3d matrix `M(:,:,i)=[]`. You might want to check for empty output: `isempty(c)`

Comment: @Ryan: and just to be sure, in you last statement you said that `size(c)` was 10x4x50. Are you sure it's not just 10x4?

Comment: thank you for your help. I will carry on trying. Yes, its 10x4x50 from size and 10x4x49 in the Workspace window: `K>> size(PortWts)

ans =

    10     4    50`

Comment: @Ryan: no I was talking about the `c` variable returned from the call, **not** the entire matrix `PortWts`. Anyway check if `c` becomes empty at any iteration as I mentioned before..

Comment: my apologies. The `isempty()` is never triggered. `size(a)

ans =

     1     1`, `size(b)

ans =

     1     1`, `size(c)

ans =

     1     4`

Comment: @Ryan: now I'm totally confused, how come they are 1x1 scalars now? It would help if you post more code (minimum working example) that we can test ourselves